# How do I run python files on github.io

Tags: python, github

I tried looking online for this a lot but I couldn't find a solution. I know how to upload files to GitHub but I have no idea on how to run python files on github.io. I can't figure out how to get them to run, and I'm pretty sure Github pages can only run HTML, CSS, or javascript. Is there any way to call python files in a different HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can call Python from HTML but you really can't host Python in GitHub Pages so you need to use another alternative like [Heroku](http://heroku.com/) or another great alternative is [Netlify](https://netlify.com)

*Side Note: Netlify and Heroku are free.*